# Is React documentation misleading while explaining Refs?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In [React documentation](https://react.dev/learn/referencing-values-with-refs#challenge), under "Referencing Values with Refs", there is a coding challenge that seems to be misleading.
In the last example (4. Read the latest state), it mentions that

> you will need both a state variable (for rendering), and a ref (to
> read it in the timeout).

However, it is possible to fix the problem only with a `ref` (no need for a state).

Is this intentional or am i missing something?

Here is a solution without `state`:

```js
import { useState, useRef } from 'react';

export default function Chat() {
  function handleSend() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      alert('Sending: ' + ref.current.value);
    }, 3000);
  }
  const ref = useRef(null);
  return (
    <>
      <input ref={ref}
      />
      <button
        onClick={handleSend}>
        Send
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: I suppose it depends on whether your input is controlled or uncontrolled. It won't have a value if it doesn't have a state association. What's the situation here?

Comment: I'm not sure that's the objective of this challenge. The challenge is - here's some existing code that uses a controlled component, now how can you get the most recent input value when the state is stale in the timeout. Removing state may work, but it's not within scope of the challenge and this shouldn't really be interpreted as a statement on better/worse/only way to do things

Comment: So in a way, your solution isn't really an answer to the challenge, it's just creating a new situation - using an uncontrolled component. This may be valid or it may not be depending on the real-world use-cases that come up

Comment: @BrianThompson 
I see your point. I was confused because it says "You need both a state and a ref" but this code alone does not need a state by just looking at the component. Of course in a context, it makes sense to have both. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

> you will need both a state variable (for rendering), and a `ref` (to read it in the timeout).
>
> > However, it is possible to fix the problem only with a `ref` (no need for a state).

Well yes, you can get the value of the `input` with just a `ref`, but suppose you want to edit the UI based on the value of the `input`, a `ref` won't be enough.

As you quoted yourself, a `ref` can be used to access the DOM, and a state is used to (eg) re-render components.

---

Suppose you need to disable a `submit` button if the `input` is empty, using a `ref` will not re-render the button (can be done ofc but with work-around),  but a `useState` will cause a re-render.

So long story short, you're comparing apples to oranges.

---

Some useful reads:

- [React: useState or useRef?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56455887/react-usestate-or-useref)
- [Use state or refs in React.js form components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29503213/use-state-or-refs-in-react-js-form-components)
- [when should I use useRef or useState in reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62586683/when-should-i-use-useref-or-usestate-in-reactjs)